# How to edit a database from another form c#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I am completely new on Visual C#. I am trying to create a program with a database to register products and costumers. I just followed these 2 walktrhoughs:

[Creating a Local Database File in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms233763.aspx)

[Connecting to Data in a Local Database File (Windows Forms)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms171890.aspx)

Then I created 3 Forms on my solution:

Form1: splash screen that is hidden after some seconds and opens the Form2.

Form2: With 4 panels, [A] to add new and edit registers for products (I dragged and dropped the table in 'Details' mode), [B] with the DataGridView which cells are configured to read Only = true. The other 2 panels are the same for costumers.

Form3: a Dialog Box that opens when double click a cell from DataGridView. This dialog box shows a product data with just few fields editable.

My problem:

If I edit a field on Form2 [A] and save it I can see the changes on the DataGridView [B] and on the Form3.

If I edit a field on Form3 and save it, then close the dialog box, there is no change on Form2 neither on panel [A] nor [B]. But when I open the Form3 again the edited data is there. And if I edit the same field on [A] that I edited on Form3 and try to save , occurs the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.DBConcurrencyException' occurred in LojaEstiloDesign20150906.exe
>
> Additional information: Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records."

---

This seems to be a very basic problem, but I have no idea how to solve it. I already tried lot of things but none have worked.
Any help will be very appreciated.

Form2:

```
namespace LojaEstiloDesign20150906
{
public partial class frm_Menu : Form
{
    public frm_Menu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void CadProdutosToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel_CadastroProdutos.Visible = true;
        panel_CadastroProdutos.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        panel_CadastroClientes.Visible = false;
        panel_ConsultaClientes.Visible = false;
        panel_ConsultaProdutos.Visible = false;
    }

    private void CadClientesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel_CadastroClientes.Visible = true;
        panel_CadastroClientes.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        panel_CadastroProdutos.Visible = false;
        panel_ConsultaClientes.Visible = false;
        panel_ConsultaProdutos.Visible = false;
    }

    private void ConProdutosToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel_ConsultaProdutos.Visible = true;
        panel_ConsultaProdutos.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        panel_CadastroClientes.Visible = false;
        panel_ConsultaClientes.Visible = false;
        panel_CadastroProdutos.Visible = false;
    }

    private void ConClientesToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel_ConsultaClientes.Visible = true;
        panel_ConsultaClientes.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        panel_CadastroClientes.Visible = false;
        panel_ConsultaProdutos.Visible = false;
        panel_CadastroProdutos.Visible = false;
    }

    private void frm_Menu_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void produtosBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Validate();
        this.produtosBindingSource.EndEdit();
        this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.lojaEstiloDataSet);

    }

    private void frm_Menu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'lojaEstiloDataSet.Clientes' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.clientesTableAdapter.Fill(this.lojaEstiloDataSet.Clientes);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'lojaEstiloDataSet.Produtos' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.produtosTableAdapter.Fill(this.lojaEstiloDataSet.Produtos);
    }

    private void produtosDataGridView_CellMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        frm_FichaProdutos frm3 = new frm_FichaProdutos();
        frm3.Show();
    }

    private void toolStripButton6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Validate();
        this.clientesBindingSource.EndEdit();
        this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.lojaEstiloDataSet);
    }
}
}
```

Form3:

```
namespace LojaEstiloDesign20150906
{
public partial class frm_FichaProdutos : Form
{
    public frm_FichaProdutos()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void frm_FichaProdutos_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'lojaEstiloDataSet.Produtos' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.produtosTableAdapter.Fill(this.lojaEstiloDataSet.Produtos);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'lojaEstiloDataSet.Produtos' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.produtosTableAdapter.Fill(this.lojaEstiloDataSet.Produtos);

    }

    public void produtosBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Validate();
        this.produtosBindingSource.EndEdit();
        this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.lojaEstiloDataSet);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: in your form3  this.produtosTableAdapter.Fill(this.lojaEstiloDataSet.Produtos); line is repeated twice. while in form2 you have  private void frm_Menu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'lojaEstiloDataSet.Clientes' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.clientesTableAdapter.Fill(this.lojaEstiloDataSet.Clientes);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'lojaEstiloDataSet.Produtos' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.produtosTableAdapter.Fill(this.lojaEstiloDataSet.Produtos);}

Comment: @amitdayama You should put this into your post. Please avoid to give answer in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADO.NET uses optimistic concurrency by default.  That means that it stores two versions of the data (original and current) and then, when you try to save modifications to existing records, it compares the original version to whats in the database to make sure that they match before saving.  The idea is that it prevents two users both retrieving the same data and both trying to save changes and having the second save overwrite the changes made in the first.

In your case, it's not two different users with two different application instances though.  It's two forms within the same application instance.  Your are retrieving the data in the first form, retrieving the data in the second form, saving changes from the second form and then trying to save changes from the first form.  The original version of the data in the first form does not match what is in the database and so a concurrency violation occurs.

You have two choices as to how to proceed.  In a valid concurrency violation, i.e. two different users, you would catch the exception and then decide what to do, which would likely be to get the data again and have the user re-edit or possibly merge their changes.  That's not the way to go in your case.  You should either throw away the data that you have in the first form and get it again when the second form closes or else don't get the same data twice in the first place.

In that second option, instead of the second form getting its own data, the first form could pass it the data that it already has.  Because there is only one copy of the data, it will always remain in sync with the database.

Comment: Thank you @jmcilhinney. It worked if I close the Form2 after opening the Form3, and then open the Form2 again when the Form3 closes.
However I would prefer doing it with the Form2 always open, how can I close the connection of the Form2 once all the database configuration was made with the wizard?

Comment: Of course it works if you close the form.  What did I say?  If you discard the data and get it again then the issue goes away.  Don't you think that closing the form and opening it again would do that?  You don't actually need to close the form though.  Just do what I actually said, i.e. discard the data you have and get it from the database again.